# Get local href value from anchor (a) tag

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have an anchor tag that has a local href value, and a JavaScript function that uses the href value but directs it to a slightly different place than it would normally go.  The tag looks like

```
<a onclick="return follow(this);" href="sec/IF00.html"></a>
```

and a JavaScript function that looks like

```
baseURL = 'http://www.someotherdomain.com/';
function follow(item) {
    location.href = baseURL + item.href;
}
```

I would expect that `item.href` would just return a short string of "sec/IF00.html", but instead it returns the full href, "http://www.thecurrentdomain.com/sec/IF00.html".  Is there a way that I can pull out just the short href as put in the anchor `<a>` tag?  Or do I lose that by natural HTML behavior?

I suppose I could use a string manipulation to do this, but it gets tricky because my local page may actually be "http://www.thecurrentdomain.com/somedir/somepath/sec/IF00.html", and my href field may or may not have a subdirectory in it (for ex `href="page.html"` vs. `href="sub/page.html"`), so I cannot always just remove every thing before the last slash.

You may wonder why I am requesting this, and it is because it will just make the page a lot cleaner.  If it is not possible to get just the short href (as put in the anchor `<a>` tag), then I could probably just insert an extra field into the tag, like `link="sec/IF00.html"`, but again, that would be a little messier.

Answer (score 420, accepted):

The below code gets the full path, where the anchor points:

```
document.getElementById("aaa").href; // http://example.com/sec/IF00.html
```

while the one below gets the value of the `href` attribute:

```
document.getElementById("aaa").getAttribute("href"); // sec/IF00.html
```

Answer (score 9):

`document.getElementById("link").getAttribute("href");`
If you have more than one `<a>` tag, for example:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="1"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="2"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="3"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can do it like this: `document.getElementById("link")[0].getAttribute("href");` to access the first array of `<a>` tags, or depends on the condition you make.

Answer (score 6):

This code works for me to get all links of the document

```
var links=document.getElementsByTagName('a'), hrefs = [];
for (var i = 0; i<links.length; i++)
{   
    hrefs.push(links[i].href);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case I had a href with a # and target.href was returning me the complete url. Target.hash did the work for me.

```
$(".test a").on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.href); // logs https://www.test.com/#test
    console.log(e.target.hash); // logs #test
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The href property sets or returns the value of the href attribute of a link.

```
  var hello = domains[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href');
    var url="https://www.google.com/";
    console.log( url+hello);
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
document.getElementById("aaa").href; //for example: http://example.com/sec/IF00.html
```

Comment: The OP already tried that, and it doesn't give him the desired results.