# Jsoup: take text and url

Tags: java, android, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I've this HTML block:

```
<div class="singolo-contenuto link_azure">
<p>I'm a TEXTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<p>
<a href="http://example.com">Name of URL</a></p></p>
<ul class="list_attachments"><li><a    
href="DON'T TOUCH"><img src='/img/fileicons/file.png' alt='file'/> TITLE</a></li></ul> 
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Actually I'm taking text with:

```
 document.select(".singolo-contenuto").text();
```

That returns to me:
"I'm a TEXTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Name of URL". Isn't possible to get "I'm a TEXTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX http://example.com Name of URL"?

are not always the same in all the pages.
I'm only sure that text and href will be in the ""singolo-contenuto link_azure" class.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439853/get-local-href-value-from-anchor-a-tag)  will be helpful to you in getting the anchor tag's `href` information. Though I'm not sure that you can impose that directly within your `div.text()` call. You could make separate calls and manipulate the Strings afterwards.

Comment: Technically, href is not text, but part of the markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all links by text as you want then call .text()

pseudo code:

```
for (Element elem : document.select(".singolo-contenuto a")) {
    if(elem.parents().hasClass("list_attachments")) continue;
    String href = elem.attr("href");
    String text = elem.text();
    elem.replaceWith(new TextNode(href + " " + text, ""));
}
String result = document.select(".singolo-contenuto").text();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggests but in this way I take also the linke in the inner class "list_attachments".
Is there a way to select (".singolo-contenuto a") exception for ".list_attachments"?

Comment: Can be done by selectors depends on your document structure i.e `.singolo-contenuto a:not(.list_attachments)` or `.singolo-contenuto :not(.list_attachments) a`. [http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

Comment: Thanks for your patience.
I edited my first post with the full structure, but your suggests doesn't works.

Comment: Read about html selectors. Combine both above into one `.singolo-contenuto a:not(.list_attachments), .singolo-contenuto :not(.list_attachments) a`

Comment: Still doesn't works :(
I'm reading for selector.. thanks for your suggests.