# Android open email client with html content in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, email, ionic-framework

I am making application in ionic and one of it's functionality to send mail so i have used [plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer)

problem is i am not able to generate link for android with **gmail version > 6.10**

Also tried to send mail using apps Gmail, Outlook, Bluemail every mail client giving different output.

**Gmail** version 6.10(ok) but 6.11(not generating links)

**Outlook** giving blank result (not event text as other mail client gives)

**Bluemail** same as Gmail

I'll be thankful if you have any solution of this.

**EDIT**
Sorry if you misunderstood "generate link" means using html content(`<a href="...">`)

Answer (score 1):

Was using the plugin myself also, lots of problems and poorly maintained, just check their `Github` issues page to confirm, use [this](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/)  instead and you can specify to send via email using `.shareViaEmail` and include link in there.

Use `var bodyText = document.getElementById("aaa").href;` to get value for link, surely you must have `<div><a href=‘YOURLINK’ id='aaa'>texthere</a></div>` in HTML. Then pass it as as a message `.shareViaEmail("PASS IT HERE",`

Comment: thanx for your quick reply @Olli

i have checked installing your suggested plugin but still the same issue as do with gmail client

Comment: Did you try passing the link as a file?

Comment: And can you include your code for generating link via the plugin I suggested?

Comment: var bodyText = “<div><a href=‘…’>texthere</a></div>”


  $cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaEmail("", “Hello Files", [], [], [], bodyText)
                             .then(function (result) {
                                 console.log(result);
                             }, function (err) {
                                  console.error( JSON.stringify(err) );
                             });

Comment: You just passed in an empty `""` in place of message didn't you? Thats where the error is

Comment: @Oli

i passed "bodyText" in place of message but error was still there

can you provide sample for this?

Comment: @Oli 

i have array of links and make html text from it and then pass that html text to mention plugin

var bodyText = “<div>”

mySplitResult.forEach(function (filename, i) {
                        var link_url = urls.server + filename;
                        bodyText += '<a href="' + link_url + '" id="test">' + filename + '</a> <br/>';
                    });
                    bodyText += "</div>";

I am not getting how to make link from it

Comment: Please format your code and include with your question above, I can't read that. If you have links, why not put in an array `[]` and then that can be extracted later on or if you have pre-defined links that can be extracted by index. JUST make sure you get the link and `console.log` to make sure you do before passing it. Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439853/get-local-href-value-from-anchor-a-tag