# Selenium WebDriver get_attribute returns truncated value of href attribute when value has entities

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-entities

I am trying to get href attribute value from anchor tab on a page in my application using selenium Webdriver (Python) and the result returned has part stripped off.

Here is the HTML snippet -

```html
<a class="nla-row-text" href="/shopping/brands?search=kamera&amp;nm=Canon&amp;page=0" data-reactid="790">
```

Here is the code I am using -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("xxxx")

url_from_attr = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"(//div[@class='nla-children mfr']/div/div/a)[1]").get_attribute("href")

url_from_attr_raw = "%r"%url_from_attr

print(" URL from attribute -->> " + url_from_attr)
print(" Raw string -->> " + url_from_attr_raw)
```

The output I am getting is -

```
/shopping/brands?search=kamera&page=0
```

instead of -

```
/shopping/brands?search=kamera&amp;nm=Canon&amp;page=0 OR
/shopping/brands?search=kamera&nm=Canon&page=0
```

Is this because of the entity representation in the URL as I see part between entities stripped? Any help or pointer would be great

Comment: Behind the scenes a call will be made to the webdriver likeso `resp = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE, {'name': name})`. Could you try to use another browser to see if you are getting the same issue? E.g. `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` Perhaps it's an issue in the geckodriver.

Comment: Well, chromedriver doesn't work either

Comment: If nothing works then always use JS. You can refer this -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver) and for getting the href using JS, refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439853/get-local-href-value-from-anchor-a-tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the given *HTML* there is a issue with the *Locator Strategy* which you have tried. You have used an index `[1]` along with `find_element` which is error-prone. Index e.g. `[1]` can be applied when a *List* is returned through `find_elements`. In this *usecase* an optimized expression would be :

```
url_from_attr = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='nla-children mfr']/div/div/a[@class='nla-row-text']").get_attribute("href")
```

The *Locator Strategy* can be more optimized as follows :

```
url_from_attr = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='nla-children mfr']//a[@class='nla-row-text']").get_attribute("href")
```

---

### Update A

As per your comment as you still need to use indexing the optimized *Locator Strategy* can be :

```
url_from_attr = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='nla-children mfr']//a[@class='nla-row-text'][1]").get_attribute("href")
```

### [get_attribute(attribute_name)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute)

As per the [*Python-API Source*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.html#WebElement.get_attribute) :

```
    def get_attribute(self, name):
    """Gets the given attribute or property of the element.

    This method will first try to return the value of a property with the
    given name. If a property with that name doesn't exist, it returns the
    value of the attribute with the same name. If there's no attribute with
    that name, ``None`` is returned.

    Values which are considered truthy, that is equals "true" or "false",
    are returned as booleans.  All other non-``None`` values are returned
    as strings.  For attributes or properties which do not exist, ``None``
    is returned.

    :Args:
        - name - Name of the attribute/property to retrieve.

    Example::

        # Check if the "active" CSS class is applied to an element.
        is_active = "active" in target_element.get_attribute("class")

    """

    attributeValue = ''
    if self._w3c:
        attributeValue = self.parent.execute_script(
        "return (%s).apply(null, arguments);" % getAttribute_js,
        self, name)
    else:
        resp = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE, {'name': name})
        attributeValue = resp.get('value')
        if attributeValue is not None:
        if name != 'value' and attributeValue.lower() in ('true', 'false'):
            attributeValue = attributeValue.lower()
    return attributeValue
```

---

### Update B

As you mentioned in your comment *the url value being returned by the method is not present anywhere on the page* which implies that you are trying to access the *href* attribute too early. So there can be 2 solutions as follows :

- Traverse the *DOM Tree* and construct a *Locator* which will uniquely identify the element and induce [*WebDriverwait*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) with **expected_conditions** as [`element_to_be_clickable`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) and then extract the *href* attribute.
- For debugging purpose you can add `time.sleep(10)` for the element to get rendered properly in the *HTML DOM* and then try to extract the *href* attribute.

Comment: The locator might not be optimized but it works. There are other anchor tags under the same div and I will need to use indexing to access the first one. It will be either the one I am currently  using or use find_elements and then accessing the first one (from the list) using the locators you have suggested, which return all. The point is, the value it returns is not present on the page which rules out the point that the loc is incorrect & is fetching some other element's href. Point taken though, will try to modify the loc,however I believe it is something to do with how get_attribute works

Comment: I am sure your locator might be optimized, however as I said, the url value being returned by the method is not present anywhere on the page. So, it is getting to the correct element but may be because of coding decoding, it is stripping some part. Also when you say - url_from_attr = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='nla-children mfr']//a[@class='nla-row-text'][1]").get_attribute("href"), you actually mean  url_from_attr = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='nla-children mfr']//a[@class='nla-row-text']")[1] and then traversing the list for get_attribute("href")

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB.  Although not exactly in the same sense that the element was taking time to load but in my complete script, the browser was moving away from the page and hence a different element was being located by the element. I moved the find_element earlier in the code and it worked