# HasMany Deep Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have 5 models with one pivot table `Country` `Province` `City` `Area` `Tour` `tour_location`. How to achieve below functionality?

`$country->tours`

`$province->tours`

`$city->tours`

`$area->tours`

Country.php **HasMany Provinces**

```
public function provinces()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Province', 'country_id', 'id');
}
```

Province.php **HasMany Cities**

```
public function cities()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\City', 'province_id', 'id');
}
```

City.php **HasMany Areas**

```
public function areas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Area', 'city_id', 'id');
}
```

Area.php **BelongsToMany Tours**

```
public function tours()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tour', 'tour_locations');
}
```

Comment: You can ckeck this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439853/get-local-href-value-from-anchor-a-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct way is do it with `join`s, another way is to make a custom relationship extending the `hasManyThrough()`. The third option -imo- is to use the [Eloquent-has-many-deep](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) package.

Using this package, you could do this:

```
class Country extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function tours()
    {
        return $this
          ->hasManyDeep('App\Tour', ['App\Province', 'App\City', 'App\Area', 'area_tour']);
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
// ...
$country = Country::find(1);
$tours = $country->tours;
```

*Disclaimer: I'm not involved in this package in any way. I'm just suggesting it because is the simplest way to achieve your desired behavior.*

Comment: yes Area has pivot table, but anyhow i got the idea.

Comment: @Fay I've updated the method with -I think- is the right way to set up your relationships. Give it a try and tell me if this worked.