# How do I get a Title of the link in AngleSharp item object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, anglesharp

Here is a link:

```
<a title = "mylink" href="mysite">content</a>
```

In AngleSharp object I can easily get `content` with this code:

```cs
string innerContent = item.TextContent;
```

But I need to get a title of the link and also a href. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that AngleSharp uses the standard DOM as defined by the W3C - thus you can just search for, e.g., "how to get href from anchor element in DOM" to retrieve an answer. For completeness, the example search query leads to (first hit on Google) [Get local href value from anchor (a) tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439853/get-local-href-value-from-anchor-a-tag), which answers your question.

Just translated to C# that means

```
var anchor = item as IHtmlAnchorElement; // Assumption: You have obtained it "only" as an IHtmlElement
string title = item.Title;
string href = item.Href;
```

Remark: There is a difference between `.GetAttribute("href")` and `.Href`. The former is *always* available (even on non-`IHtmlAnchorElement`) and gives you the *real* value. The latter is a special computed version available on some elements (e.g., `IHtmlAnchorElement`) and will get you a *normalized* version, already considering the base URL of the current document.

TL;DR: `.Href` will give you an absolute URL while `.GetAttribute("href")` may give you a relative URL.

HTH!