# Unable to access the href attribute of links

Tags: javascript

I want to access the `href` attribute of some links and make changes to them if they contain certain string. Here is my current code:

```
var all_links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for(var i = 0; i <= all_links.length; i++) {
   if(all_links[i].href.includes('test')) {
     all_links[i].href = 'something.com/?' + all_links[i].href;
   }
}
```

The code keeps giving me error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined
```

However, there are definitely  lot of links on the webpage. I could get all links in the console by using:

```
console.log(all_links[i]);
```

Why can't I access the `href` attribute?

Here is the question I was following: [Get local href value from anchor (a) tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439853/get-local-href-value-from-anchor-a-tag)

Comment: change  `i <= all_links.length` to  `i < all_links.length`.
Otherwise it will always try to read one more element than there are elements in the list. The error only occures when your code tries to do this: `undefined.href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `<=` with `<` since arrays are zero indexed.

```
for(var i = 0; i < all_links.length; i++)
```

Or use filter and forEach

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'))
    .filter(({href}) => href.includes('test'))
    .forEach(link => link.href = `something.com/?${href}`);
```