# How to reference id and get href of a link?

Tags: javascript, anchor, href, concatenation

**Question** : How to reference id of a link? See the **attached image**
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoRTw.jpg)

```
function insertButton(refresh = false) {
var to_match = 'a[class="';
var PAGE_TYPE = 0;

if (document.location.href == "https://www.youtube.com") {
```

How to reference **id = "video-title-link"**

```
var anchor_tag = document.getElementById("video-title-link");
```

There are **2 anchor tags*** with the same **class name**. I would like to reference the **id ="video-title-link"**

```
  if(anchor_tag.hasAttribute('href="\/watch\?v=(\S+)"')){

    to_match = to_match.concat("yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-rich-grid-video-renderer", '"]').getattribute('id ="video-title-link"');
    PAGE_TYPE = 1;

  } 

}
```

**UPDATE :** **POLLING**

```
const poller = setInterval(function(){  
    
  const anchor_tags = document.querySelectorAll('a[id="video-title-link"]'); 
  
    if(anchor_tags){
  
        for (index = 0; index < anchor_tags.length ; index++){
            
            console.log(anchor_tags[index].getAttribute('href'));
            
        }   
        
        clearInterval(poller);
        
    }   
    
}, 1000);
```

**OUTPUT :** [Click here :  href of each 'id'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaFNO.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you give us more information about, what exactly you need to do?

Comment: You have to explain what you want to do here? What have you tried? on which event you want to get the href?

Comment: Please include all code as text, not as pictures of text. Also explain how the HTML you show in that image relates to the JavaScript, and how you are planning on using that JavaScript.

Comment: If you just want the href of a link, you can grab it by using a querySelector, and then looking at the href: `document.querySelector('#classnamehere').href`. This will give you the full path of the href.

Comment: Note that unless you're writing this code for Google, `document.location.href` is unlikely to be "https://www.youtube.com" unless you're running code in the console or an extension.

Comment: @RobertStefanic - There are two <a> tags with the same classname. I want the one which has 'href = "/watch?v=iKIhfmiy4II"?

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Code is in the extension

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get local href value from anchor (a) tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439853/get-local-href-value-from-anchor-a-tag)

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I should be able to reference the 2nd <a> tag using this :
to_match = to_match.concat("yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-rich-grid-video-renderer", '"]');

Comment: Was that a question? `to_match` is a string. It doesn't reference anything until you use it with `querySelector` or some other mechanism to select something in the DOM. The linked question's answers answer the question of how to get the `href` attribute of an anchor element.

Comment: @NaveenChandraTiwari - On <a> tag which has "href = /watch?"

Comment: @NaveenChandraTiwari - Can you have a look at it? I'll share the source code

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Can you have a look at it? I'll share the source code

Comment: Nah. You've changed the question and invalidated the answer, which is unfair to the answerer. Sharing the code is a requirement of the site, not something you withhold to get people to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `querySelector()` and `.getAttribute()` to do this:

```js
const element = document.querySelector(".yt-simple-endpoint")
const href = element.getAttribute("href");
console.log(href)
```

```html
<a class="yt-simple-endpoint" href="https://example.com">Link</a>
```