# How to obtain url from a table cell using javascript

Tags: javascript

The table cell has following content dynamically generated :

```html
<a href="abc.com" target="_blank" specname="hyperlink" ><span tabindex="-1" ctx="2380" specname="textItem" >URL</span></a>
```

I am looping through the table cells using javascript and for hyperlinked cells, I want to obtain the url in the href section.

With

```
 <cell>.innerText // I can get the text part i.e. "URL" 
 <cell>.innerHTML // I get the complete content of the cell shown above.     
 <cell>.getAttribute('href') // doesnt work - returns undefined
```

Any ideas how can I get just the url in the href property.

Comment: Is your URL in an `<a>` tag? I would think you should be able to do a querySelector on your cell DOM if that's the case. Either that or a child node. Perhaps start [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp).

Comment: `href` is an attribute of the `<a>` element and not the "cell". The `<a>` is also a child of the "cell". The "cell" has a `.children` property, or `.querySelector()`, or, ...

Comment: Can you post how you're lopping through table cells?

Comment: Does this work in your case?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439946/1351883