# jQuery getting link from a div class inside multiple divs?

Tags: html, jquery, href

I'am trying to get a link from the  but somehow I'm getting a weird result.

My expected result is: https://www.trendyol.com/join-us/kadin-somon-bisiklet-yaka-triko-kazak-ju19-20w-cbs-01-p-32897396

What I'am getting is: `/search?sxsrf=ALeKk004fBqm96IZaXzZy1RlXkZF6SPc7Q:1618910936715&amp;source=univ&amp;tbm=isch&amp;q=ju19-20w-cbs-01+sari&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQjJkEegQIBxAB`

However, here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  <!--**BELOW THE PATH FROM THE MAIN DIV TO THE TARGETED DIV:**-->
    alert($(".rso, #hlcw0c, #g, #tF2Cxc, #yuRUbf, a").attr("href"));
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div eid="2J5-YI6MK4zykwXW177YDw" data-async-context="query:ju19-20w-cbs-01%20sari" id="rso"><div class="ULSxyf"><div jsmodel="gpo5Gf" class="LnbJhc" data-count="12" style="position:relative" data-iu="1" data-hveid="CAcQAA" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQyA0oAHoECAcQAA"><g-section-with-header><div class="e2BEnf U7izfe mfMhoc"><title-with-lhs-icon><a class="ekf0x hSQtef" href="/search?sxsrf=ALeKk004fBqm96IZaXzZy1RlXkZF6SPc7Q:1618910936715&amp;source=univ&amp;tbm=isch&amp;q=ju19-20w-cbs-01+sari&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQjJkEegQIBxAB"><div class="iv236 kNmTT"><span class="iJddsb" style="height:20px;width:20px"><svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M14 13l4 5H6l4-4 1.79 1.78L14 13zm-6.01-2.99A2 2 0 0 0 8 6a2 2 0 0 0-.01 4.01zM22 5v14a3 3 0 0 1-3 2.99H5c-1.64 0-3-1.36-3-3V5c0-1.64 1.36-3 3-3h14c1.65 0 3 1.36 3 3zm-2.01 0a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v14a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h7v-.01h7a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V5"></path></svg></span></div><div class="dtIg1b"><span class="iJddsb" style="height:20px;width:20px"><svg clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#4285f4" d="M19 22h-7v-2h7c.55 0 1-.46 1-1V5a1 1 0 0 0-1-.99L12 4V2h7c1.66 0 3 1.36 3 3v14c0 1.65-1.35 3-3 3"></path><path fill="#ea4335" d="M12 22H5c-1.64 0-3-1.36-3-3V5c0-1.64 1.36-3 3-3h7v2H5c-.55 0-.99.45-.99 1L4 19c0 .55.45 1 1 1h7v2"></path><path fill="#34a853" d="M14 13l-2.25 2.75L10 14l-4 4h12"></path><path fill="#fbbc04" d="M10 8c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2s-2-.9-2-2c0-1.09.9-2 2-2s2 .9 2 2"></path></svg></span></div><div class="iJ1Kvb"><h3 class="GmE3X" aria-level="2" role="heading">ju19-20w-cbs-01 sari ile ilgili görseller</h3></div></a></title-with-lhs-icon></div><div id="iur"><div><div jsmodel="" jscontroller="IkchZc" jsaction="PdWSXe:h5M12e;rcuQ6b:npT2md" jsdata="X2sNs;_;BS0J+c"><div data-h="130" data-nr="2" style="margin-right:-2px;margin-bottom:-2px"><div jsname="dTDiAc" class="eA0Zlc qN5nNb tapJqb ivg-i" data-docid="gIGy7cXIiIl-LM" jsdata="XZxcdf;gIGy7cXIiIl-LM;BS0J+8" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ9AF6BAgUEAA"><a href="/search?q=ju19-20w-cbs-01+sari&amp;sxsrf=ALeKk004fBqm96IZaXzZy1RlXkZF6SPc7Q:1618910936715&amp;tbm=isch&amp;source=iu&amp;ictx=1&amp;fir=gIGy7cXIiIl-LM%252CwrTGjH9PgPL6hM%252C_&amp;vet=1&amp;usg=AI4_-kRMrXLVyDzuzmDrKj32HPO97Ldx0w&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ9QF6BAgUEAE#imgrc=gIGy7cXIiIl-LM" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ9QF6BAgUEAE"><g-img class="GMCzAd BA0A6c" style="height:156px;width:102px;position:relative"><img id="dimg_45" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsUFsx0htT+flUsNUaP8AyPOnVpL22T0jIUs6A4uWNBbxkmrjLMOsag1VyC2Zy+taTDqAiC2xan+E+ucQPxYx0+1dqL0uI/uRnqWNdoBUrHq6RaKdUbUlYZ//2Q==" class="rISBZc M4dUYb" height="156" style="margin-left:-1px;margin-right:-1px" title="https://www.trendyol.com/join-us/kadin-mavi-bisiklet-yaka-triko-kazak-ju19-20w-cbs-01-p-32897399" width="104" alt="ju19-20w-cbs-01 sari ile ilgili görsel sonucu" data-atf="1"><div class="fWhgmd"></div></g-img></a></div><div jsname="dTDiAc" class="eA0Zlc qN5nNb tapJqb ivg-i" data-docid="AYdKIuMYZf3MQM" jsdata="XZxcdf;AYdKIuMYZf3MQM;BS0J+4" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ9AF6BAgTEAA"><a href="/search?q=ju19-20w-cbs-01+sari&amp;sxsrf=ALeKk004fBqm96IZaXzZy1RlXkZF6SPc7Q:1618910936715&amp;tbm=isch&amp;source=iu&amp;ictx=1&amp;fir=AYdKIuMYZf3MQM%252CXNUnTWS0l-OJzM%252C_&amp;vet=1&amp;usg=AI4_-kQX7ByGaKKMho14vvwctY-OcMecjA&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ9QF6BAgTEAE#imgrc=AYdKIuMYZf3MQM" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ9QF6BAgTEAE"><g-img class="GMCzAd BA0A6c" style="height:156px;width:102px;position:relative"><img id="dimg_43" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="rISBZc M4dUYb" height="155" style="margin-left:-3px;margin-right:-4px" title="https://www.morhipo.com/mimoza-ju19-20w-297-bisiklet-yaka-neon-cizgili/30164058/detay" width="113" alt="ju19-20w-cbs-01 sari ile ilgili görsel sonucu" data-atf="1"><div class="fWhgmd"></div></g-img></a></div></div></div></div></div><div class="wFKnCb"><span class="SjnGOc" jscontroller="WVLMce" data-rc="ivg-i"><input style="display:none" class="iri" value="Rapor et" type="button"><span class="nucC7d iri" style="display:none">Rapor edildi</span><span class="TvcMHf"><span jsname="uQPRwe" class="kkg8oe nucC7d yoSdhc"><a class="JSTKkb a-no-hover-decoration" href="#" jsaction="rcuQ6b">Görseller hakkında kötüye kullanım bildirin</a></span><span jsname="a8amEf" class="nucC7d" style="display:none">Geribildirim için teşekkür ederiz.</span><span jsname="z5C9Gb" class="kkg8oe nucC7d" style="display:none">&nbsp;<a href="#" jsaction="rcuQ6b">Başka bir görseli rapor et</a></span><span jsname="ostUZ" class="nucC7d B8tSoe" style="display:none">Lütfen rahatsız edici görseli rapor edin.</span><span jsname="IbE0S" class="kkg8oe nucC7d" style="display:none">&nbsp;<a class="wh2ucd XAWeZb" href="#" jsaction="IbE0S">İptal</a></span><span jsname="iib5kc" class="kkg8oe nucC7d" style="display:none"><a href="#" jsaction="iib5kc">Bitti</a></span></span></span><g-more-link class="KqWjY mIKy0c dGWpb"><a class="Q2MMlc" href="/search?sxsrf=ALeKk004fBqm96IZaXzZy1RlXkZF6SPc7Q:1618910936715&amp;source=univ&amp;tbm=isch&amp;q=ju19-20w-cbs-01+sari&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ7Al6BAgHEAQ"><hr class="pb5vrc"><div class="MXl0lf mtqGb EhIML" aria-label="Diğer resimler"><span class="EZRelc z1asCe lYxQe"><svg focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 4l-1.41 1.41L16.17 11H4v2h12.17l-5.58 5.59L12 20l8-8z"></path></svg></span><span class="wUrVib">Tümünü görüntüle</span></div></a></g-more-link></div></g-section-with-header></div></div><div class="hlcw0c"><div class="g"><h2 class="Uo8X3b">Web sonuçları</h2><div data-hveid="CAMQAA" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQFSgAMAx6BAgDEAA"><div class="tF2Cxc"><div class="yuRUbf"><a href="https://www.trendyol.com/join-us/kadin-somon-bisiklet-yaka-triko-kazak-ju19-20w-cbs-01-p-32897396" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQFjAMegQIAxAD" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://www.trendyol.com/join-us/kadin-somon-bisiklet-yaka-triko-kazak-ju19-20w-cbs-01-p-32897396&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQFjAMegQIAxAD"><br><h3 class="LC20lb DKV0Md">JOIN US Kadın Somon Bisiklet Yaka Triko Kazak JU19-20W ...</h3><div class="TbwUpd NJjxre"><cite class="iUh30 Zu0yb qLRx3b tjvcx">https://www.trendyol.com<span class="dyjrff qzEoUe"> › join-us › kadin-somon-bisi...</span></cite></div></a><div class="B6fmyf"><div class="TbwUpd"><cite class="iUh30 Zu0yb qLRx3b tjvcx">https://www.trendyol.com<span class="dyjrff qzEoUe"> › join-us › kadin-somon-bisi...</span></cite></div><div class="eFM0qc"><span><div jscontroller="hiU8Ie" class="action-menu"><a class="GHDvEf" href="#" id="am-b12" aria-label="Sonuç Seçenekleri" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="PZcoEd;keydown:wU6FVd;keypress:uWmNaf" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ7B0wDHoECAMQBg"><span class="gTl8xb"></span></a><ol class="action-menu-panel" role="menu" tabindex="-1" jsaction="keydown:Xiq7wd;mouseover:pKPowd;mouseout:O9bKS" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQqR8wDHoECAMQBw"><li class="action-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:XNUnTWS0l-MJ:https://www.trendyol.com/join-us/kadin-somon-bisiklet-yaka-triko-kazak-ju19-20w-cbs-01-p-32897396+&amp;cd=13&amp;hl=tr&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=tr" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:XNUnTWS0l-MJ:https://www.trendyol.com/join-us/kadin-somon-bisiklet-yaka-triko-kazak-ju19-20w-cbs-01-p-32897396%2B%26cd%3D13%26hl%3Dtr%26ct%3Dclnk%26gl%3Dtr&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQIDAMegQIAxAI"><span>Önbellek</span></a></li></ol></div></span></div></div></div><div class="IsZvec"><span class="aCOpRe"><span>Join Us Kadın Somon Bisiklet Yaka Triko Kazak <em>JU19</em>-<em>20W</em>-<em>CBS</em>-<em>01</em>. Henüz Yorum Yazılmamış. Tükendi. Ürün Bilgileri ????? %46 Akrilik %44 Polyester %<wbr>10&nbsp;...</span></span><div class="TXwUJf"><span>Eksik:</span> <s><span>sari</span></s> &lrm;| Şunları içermelidir: <a class="fl" href="/search?sxsrf=ALeKk004fBqm96IZaXzZy1RlXkZF6SPc7Q:1618910936715&amp;q=ju19-20w-cbs-01+%22sari%22&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ5t4CMAx6BAgDEAo"><span>sari</span></a></div></div><div jscontroller="m6a0l" id="eob_17" jsdata="fxg5tf;_;BS0J94" jsaction="rcuQ6b:npT2md" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ2Z0BMAx6BAgDEAs"><div jsname="UTgHCf" class="AUiS2" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQx40DegQIIhAA"><div jsname="d3PE6e" style="display:none"><div data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQsKwBKAB6BAgiEAE">Joinus yorumlar</div><div data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQsKwBKAF6BAgiEAI">Jounıs</div><div data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQsKwBKAJ6BAgiEAM">Join Us nerenin Markası</div><div data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQsKwBKAN6BAgiEAQ">Join US Yeni SEZON</div><div data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQsKwBKAR6BAgiEAU">Joinus indirim kodu</div><div data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQsKwBKAV6BAgiEAY">Join Us İndirim</div></div><div><div jsname="l1CLDf" class="d8lLoc"><h4 jsname="IaVMje" class="eJ7tvc">Kullanıcıların yaptığı diğer aramalar</h4><span jsname="ZnuYW" class="XCKyNd" jsaction="ornU0b" aria-label="Takip edilmesi önerilen içerikleri kapat" role="button" tabindex="0"></span><div jsname="CeevUc" class="hYkSRb" style="display:none"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>

<button>Show href Value</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you console.log the result of your currnet selector, you'll see that you're getting the wrong element: `console.log($(".rso, #hlcw0c, #g, #tF2Cxc, #yuRUbf, a"));`.

`$('.yuRUbf a')[0].href` should do the trick. No need for those extra class selectors.

Also, jquery selectors return DOM elements, so we can just use the regular `.href` to get the url. <sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439853/get-local-href-value-from-anchor-a-tag)</sup>

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  const el = $('.yuRUbf a')[0].href;
  console.log(el);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div eid="2J5-YI6MK4zykwXW177YDw" data-async-context="query:ju19-20w-cbs-01%20sari" id="rso"><div class="ULSxyf"><div jsmodel="gpo5Gf" class="LnbJhc" data-count="12" style="position:relative" data-iu="1" data-hveid="CAcQAA" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQyA0oAHoECAcQAA"><g-section-with-header><div class="e2BEnf U7izfe mfMhoc"><title-with-lhs-icon><a class="ekf0x hSQtef" href="/search?sxsrf=ALeKk004fBqm96IZaXzZy1RlXkZF6SPc7Q:1618910936715&amp;source=univ&amp;tbm=isch&amp;q=ju19-20w-cbs-01+sari&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQjJkEegQIBxAB"><div class="iv236 kNmTT"><span class="iJddsb" style="height:20px;width:20px"><svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M14 13l4 5H6l4-4 1.79 1.78L14 13zm-6.01-2.99A2 2 0 0 0 8 6a2 2 0 0 0-.01 4.01zM22 5v14a3 3 0 0 1-3 2.99H5c-1.64 0-3-1.36-3-3V5c0-1.64 1.36-3 3-3h14c1.65 0 3 1.36 3 3zm-2.01 0a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v14a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h7v-.01h7a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V5"></path></svg></span></div><div class="dtIg1b"><span class="iJddsb" style="height:20px;width:20px"><svg clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#4285f4" d="M19 22h-7v-2h7c.55 0 1-.46 1-1V5a1 1 0 0 0-1-.99L12 4V2h7c1.66 0 3 1.36 3 3v14c0 1.65-1.35 3-3 3"></path><path fill="#ea4335" d="M12 22H5c-1.64 0-3-1.36-3-3V5c0-1.64 1.36-3 3-3h7v2H5c-.55 0-.99.45-.99 1L4 19c0 .55.45 1 1 1h7v2"></path><path fill="#34a853" d="M14 13l-2.25 2.75L10 14l-4 4h12"></path><path fill="#fbbc04" d="M10 8c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2s-2-.9-2-2c0-1.09.9-2 2-2s2 .9 2 2"></path></svg></span></div><div class="iJ1Kvb"><h3 class="GmE3X" aria-level="2" role="heading">ju19-20w-cbs-01 sari ile ilgili görseller</h3></div></a></title-with-lhs-icon></div><div id="iur"><div><div jsmodel="" jscontroller="IkchZc" jsaction="PdWSXe:h5M12e;rcuQ6b:npT2md" jsdata="X2sNs;_;BS0J+c"><div data-h="130" data-nr="2" style="margin-right:-2px;margin-bottom:-2px"><div jsname="dTDiAc" class="eA0Zlc qN5nNb tapJqb ivg-i" data-docid="gIGy7cXIiIl-LM" jsdata="XZxcdf;gIGy7cXIiIl-LM;BS0J+8" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ9AF6BAgUEAA"><a href="/search?q=ju19-20w-cbs-01+sari&amp;sxsrf=ALeKk004fBqm96IZaXzZy1RlXkZF6SPc7Q:1618910936715&amp;tbm=isch&amp;source=iu&amp;ictx=1&amp;fir=gIGy7cXIiIl-LM%252CwrTGjH9PgPL6hM%252C_&amp;vet=1&amp;usg=AI4_-kRMrXLVyDzuzmDrKj32HPO97Ldx0w&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ9QF6BAgUEAE#imgrc=gIGy7cXIiIl-LM" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ9QF6BAgUEAE"><g-img class="GMCzAd BA0A6c" style="height:156px;width:102px;position:relative"><img id="dimg_45" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsUFsx0htT+flUsNUaP8AyPOnVpL22T0jIUs6A4uWNBbxkmrjLMOsag1VyC2Zy+taTDqAiC2xan+E+ucQPxYx0+1dqL0uI/uRnqWNdoBUrHq6RaKdUbUlYZ//2Q==" class="rISBZc M4dUYb" height="156" style="margin-left:-1px;margin-right:-1px" title="https://www.trendyol.com/join-us/kadin-mavi-bisiklet-yaka-triko-kazak-ju19-20w-cbs-01-p-32897399" width="104" alt="ju19-20w-cbs-01 sari ile ilgili görsel sonucu" data-atf="1"><div class="fWhgmd"></div></g-img></a></div><div jsname="dTDiAc" class="eA0Zlc qN5nNb tapJqb ivg-i" data-docid="AYdKIuMYZf3MQM" jsdata="XZxcdf;AYdKIuMYZf3MQM;BS0J+4" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ9AF6BAgTEAA"><a href="/search?q=ju19-20w-cbs-01+sari&amp;sxsrf=ALeKk004fBqm96IZaXzZy1RlXkZF6SPc7Q:1618910936715&amp;tbm=isch&amp;source=iu&amp;ictx=1&amp;fir=AYdKIuMYZf3MQM%252CXNUnTWS0l-OJzM%252C_&amp;vet=1&amp;usg=AI4_-kQX7ByGaKKMho14vvwctY-OcMecjA&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ9QF6BAgTEAE#imgrc=AYdKIuMYZf3MQM" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ9QF6BAgTEAE"><g-img class="GMCzAd BA0A6c" style="height:156px;width:102px;position:relative"><img id="dimg_43" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="rISBZc M4dUYb" height="155" style="margin-left:-3px;margin-right:-4px" title="https://www.morhipo.com/mimoza-ju19-20w-297-bisiklet-yaka-neon-cizgili/30164058/detay" width="113" alt="ju19-20w-cbs-01 sari ile ilgili görsel sonucu" data-atf="1"><div class="fWhgmd"></div></g-img></a></div></div></div></div></div><div class="wFKnCb"><span class="SjnGOc" jscontroller="WVLMce" data-rc="ivg-i"><input style="display:none" class="iri" value="Rapor et" type="button"><span class="nucC7d iri" style="display:none">Rapor edildi</span><span class="TvcMHf"><span jsname="uQPRwe" class="kkg8oe nucC7d yoSdhc"><a class="JSTKkb a-no-hover-decoration" href="#" jsaction="rcuQ6b">Görseller hakkında kötüye kullanım bildirin</a></span><span jsname="a8amEf" class="nucC7d" style="display:none">Geribildirim için teşekkür ederiz.</span><span jsname="z5C9Gb" class="kkg8oe nucC7d" style="display:none">&nbsp;<a href="#" jsaction="rcuQ6b">Başka bir görseli rapor et</a></span><span jsname="ostUZ" class="nucC7d B8tSoe" style="display:none">Lütfen rahatsız edici görseli rapor edin.</span><span jsname="IbE0S" class="kkg8oe nucC7d" style="display:none">&nbsp;<a class="wh2ucd XAWeZb" href="#" jsaction="IbE0S">İptal</a></span><span jsname="iib5kc" class="kkg8oe nucC7d" style="display:none"><a href="#" jsaction="iib5kc">Bitti</a></span></span></span><g-more-link class="KqWjY mIKy0c dGWpb"><a class="Q2MMlc" href="/search?sxsrf=ALeKk004fBqm96IZaXzZy1RlXkZF6SPc7Q:1618910936715&amp;source=univ&amp;tbm=isch&amp;q=ju19-20w-cbs-01+sari&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ7Al6BAgHEAQ"><hr class="pb5vrc"><div class="MXl0lf mtqGb EhIML" aria-label="Diğer resimler"><span class="EZRelc z1asCe lYxQe"><svg focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 4l-1.41 1.41L16.17 11H4v2h12.17l-5.58 5.59L12 20l8-8z"></path></svg></span><span class="wUrVib">Tümünü görüntüle</span></div></a></g-more-link></div></g-section-with-header></div></div><div class="hlcw0c"><div class="g"><h2 class="Uo8X3b">Web sonuçları</h2><div data-hveid="CAMQAA" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQFSgAMAx6BAgDEAA"><div class="tF2Cxc"><div class="yuRUbf"><a href="https://www.trendyol.com/join-us/kadin-somon-bisiklet-yaka-triko-kazak-ju19-20w-cbs-01-p-32897396" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQFjAMegQIAxAD" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://www.trendyol.com/join-us/kadin-somon-bisiklet-yaka-triko-kazak-ju19-20w-cbs-01-p-32897396&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQFjAMegQIAxAD"><br><h3 class="LC20lb DKV0Md">JOIN US Kadın Somon Bisiklet Yaka Triko Kazak JU19-20W ...</h3><div class="TbwUpd NJjxre"><cite class="iUh30 Zu0yb qLRx3b tjvcx">https://www.trendyol.com<span class="dyjrff qzEoUe"> › join-us › kadin-somon-bisi...</span></cite></div></a><div class="B6fmyf"><div class="TbwUpd"><cite class="iUh30 Zu0yb qLRx3b tjvcx">https://www.trendyol.com<span class="dyjrff qzEoUe"> › join-us › kadin-somon-bisi...</span></cite></div><div class="eFM0qc"><span><div jscontroller="hiU8Ie" class="action-menu"><a class="GHDvEf" href="#" id="am-b12" aria-label="Sonuç Seçenekleri" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="PZcoEd;keydown:wU6FVd;keypress:uWmNaf" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ7B0wDHoECAMQBg"><span class="gTl8xb"></span></a><ol class="action-menu-panel" role="menu" tabindex="-1" jsaction="keydown:Xiq7wd;mouseover:pKPowd;mouseout:O9bKS" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQqR8wDHoECAMQBw"><li class="action-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:XNUnTWS0l-MJ:https://www.trendyol.com/join-us/kadin-somon-bisiklet-yaka-triko-kazak-ju19-20w-cbs-01-p-32897396+&amp;cd=13&amp;hl=tr&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=tr" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:XNUnTWS0l-MJ:https://www.trendyol.com/join-us/kadin-somon-bisiklet-yaka-triko-kazak-ju19-20w-cbs-01-p-32897396%2B%26cd%3D13%26hl%3Dtr%26ct%3Dclnk%26gl%3Dtr&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQIDAMegQIAxAI"><span>Önbellek</span></a></li></ol></div></span></div></div></div><div class="IsZvec"><span class="aCOpRe"><span>Join Us Kadın Somon Bisiklet Yaka Triko Kazak <em>JU19</em>-<em>20W</em>-<em>CBS</em>-<em>01</em>. Henüz Yorum Yazılmamış. Tükendi. Ürün Bilgileri ????? %46 Akrilik %44 Polyester %<wbr>10&nbsp;...</span></span><div class="TXwUJf"><span>Eksik:</span> <s><span>sari</span></s> &lrm;| Şunları içermelidir: <a class="fl" href="/search?sxsrf=ALeKk004fBqm96IZaXzZy1RlXkZF6SPc7Q:1618910936715&amp;q=ju19-20w-cbs-01+%22sari%22&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ5t4CMAx6BAgDEAo"><span>sari</span></a></div></div><div jscontroller="m6a0l" id="eob_17" jsdata="fxg5tf;_;BS0J94" jsaction="rcuQ6b:npT2md" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQ2Z0BMAx6BAgDEAs"><div jsname="UTgHCf" class="AUiS2" data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQx40DegQIIhAA"><div jsname="d3PE6e" style="display:none"><div data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQsKwBKAB6BAgiEAE">Joinus yorumlar</div><div data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQsKwBKAF6BAgiEAI">Jounıs</div><div data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQsKwBKAJ6BAgiEAM">Join Us nerenin Markası</div><div data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQsKwBKAN6BAgiEAQ">Join US Yeni SEZON</div><div data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQsKwBKAR6BAgiEAU">Joinus indirim kodu</div><div data-ved="2ahUKEwiO2LiawYzwAhUM-aQKHdarD_sQsKwBKAV6BAgiEAY">Join Us İndirim</div></div><div><div jsname="l1CLDf" class="d8lLoc"><h4 jsname="IaVMje" class="eJ7tvc">Kullanıcıların yaptığı diğer aramalar</h4><span jsname="ZnuYW" class="XCKyNd" jsaction="ornU0b" aria-label="Takip edilmesi önerilen içerikleri kapat" role="button" tabindex="0"></span><div jsname="CeevUc" class="hYkSRb" style="display:none"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this CSS selector `$(".rso #hlcw0c #g #tF2Cxc #yuRUbf a").attr("href")`