# how to get the href value of a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

when i input the command

```
document.getElementsByClassName('grid')[5] :
```

i get this :[TEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bRWd.png)

HOwever i struggle finding how to get the href value (a link here), i have thought about using GetAttribute but it does no work

Comment: You can try something like this: document.getElementsByClassName('grid')[5].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get local href value from anchor (a) tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439853/get-local-href-value-from-anchor-a-tag)

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're selecting the `<div>` parent instead of `<a>`, div's doesn't have href attribute.

You can get the href by doing:

```
const $parentDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.grid')[5];
const $anchor = $parentDiv.querySelector('a');
console.log($anchor.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use children property to get the  tag, and get the href thereafter

Comment: If you could explain the process with an example, it'll be good for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways how you can do that

**1** -

You can add an id attribute to the `<a>` tag and then use `document.getElementById("yourid").getAttribute("href");`

**2** =

As mentioned by Eliabe Franca -

```js
const $parentDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.grid')[5];
const $anchor = $parentDiv.querySelector('a');
console.log($anchor.href);
```

What this does is that it first gets the `.grid[5]` element and then gets the first `<a>` in it. The last line will help you get the `href` value.