# How to get the hyperlink in a tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, href

Here I have an html with javascript:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  let elem = event.target;
  let jsonObject = {
    Key: 'mousedown',
    Value: event.button
  };
  if (event.button == 2) {
    console.log(elem.outerHTML);
  }
});
```

```html
<span style="font-size:xx-large">
    <a href="https://microsoft.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" shape="rect" style="color:rgb(17,85,204)">
        <i>
            <font color="#ff0000">Microsoft</font>
        </i>
    </a>
</span>
<br/>
<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
<div>
```

When I right click the link, it should alert me the hyperlink inside.

The `Google` works fine. But when right click `Microsoft`, it always returns the `font` tag.

I also tried this, still not work:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event)
                              {
                                let elem = event.target;
                                let name = elem.tagName;
                                let jsonObject =
                                {
                                    Key: 'mousemove',
                                    Value: name == 'A' ? elem.outerHTML : ' '
                                };

                                if(event.button == 2 && name == 'A') 
                                  {alert(elem.outerHTML);}
                              });
```

Is there a general method for getting the links in the `a` tags?

Comment: The solution to get the href form an anchor tag is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439853/get-local-href-value-from-anchor-a-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse the parent nodes until you find the anchor, like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
  let elem = event.target;
  while(elem && elem.tagName!=='A') elem = elem.parentElement; 
  if(elem) {
    let jsonObject = 
    {
        Key: 'mousedown',
        Value: event.button
    };
    if(event.button == 2) {alert(elem.href);}
  }
});
```

```html
<span style="font-size:xx-large">
    <a href="https://microsoft.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" shape="rect" style="color:rgb(17,85,204)">
        <i>
            <font color="#ff0000">Microsoft</font>
        </i>
    </a>
</span>
<br/>
<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Closest should do it

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  let elem = event.target.closest("a");
  if (!elem) return; // not a link
  let jsonObject = {
    Key: 'mousedown',
    Value: event.button
  };
  if (event.button == 2) {
    console.log(elem.textContent.trim(),":",elem.href,"\n",elem.outerHTML);
  }
});
```

```html
<span style="font-size:xx-large">
    <a href="https://microsoft.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" shape="rect" style="color:rgb(17,85,204)">
        <i>
            <font color="#ff0000">Microsoft</font>
        </i>
    </a>
</span>
<br/>
<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
<div>
```